How to iterate over a specific column to create a line graph
beginner coder here. The issue im running into is the use of a for loop to iterate over a specific column to generate a line graph.
dataframe first 5 rows
the df is a collection of information on films, specifically title, studio,year, domestic, foreign and total gross.
I'm trying to use a for loop to add up the sums of all total gross for each year, i.e all of the total gross for 2012 added up, and the same for the rest of the years, to create a graph with a point at the sums for each year. so lets say 2012 had 200b in total gross and 2013 had 150b in total gross.
I already created a function to find the total gross for an individual year, but struggle with the for loop as for loops are a weakness of mine. also i don't want to hardcode the values in for each data point as that obviously won't be viable with larger data collections, and i want to learn how to do it with for loops anyways.
the original attempt at making the plot looked like so:
x = np.array(df['year'])
y = np.array(df['total_gross'])
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show();

this created a chart with vertical lines for each year. This is when i realized its not summing each years values, and is just simply placing each gross_value at its own place.
here is the function i created to gather a years total gross
 def year_gross(year):
    year_list = df[df['year'] == year]
    gross = sum(year_list['total_gross'])
    return gross

it works fine but like i said earlier, i want to avoid hardcoding.

Totally unclear. "I struggle with for loops" doesn't make a valid question [ask] and [mre]

do not use for loops with dataframes. vectorization
